# Android Google map shows black screen before loading

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an application with an initial window with three buttons. When I click on one of them, I start a progress dialog while I am loading a Google Map V2 and drawing some markers on it.

In the onMapReady callback I dismiss the progress dialog:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {

    Log.i(MyMoneyBackActivity.TAG, "ShopsMapActivity onMapReady");

    GMap = map;


    if (needsInit) {
      CameraUpdate center=
          CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(CAMERA_LAT,
                                               CAMERA_LNG));
      CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12f);

      map.moveCamera(center);
      map.animateCamera(zoom);
    }


    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Clears all the existing coordinates
    map.clear();        

    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get best last location measurement
    mBestReading = bestLastKnownLocation(MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY, FIVE_MIN);

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

    Log.i(MyMoneyBackActivity.TAG, "Map");


    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(ShopsMapActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

    if ( geoCoder.isPresent() )
        Log.i(MyMoneyBackActivity.TAG, "Geocoder available");
    else
        Log.i(MyMoneyBackActivity.TAG, "Geocoder NOT available");


    // Add a marker for every shop

    for (ShopElement rec : MyMoneyBackActivity.shopElementsList) { 

        //String addressStr = "Aquileia 39,Udine,Italy"; 
        String addressStr = rec.getaddress() + "," + rec.getcity() +",Italy";
        Log.i(MyMoneyBackActivity.TAG, "addressStr -" + addressStr + "-");


          try {
              List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(addressStr, 1); 
              if (addresses.size() >  0) {
                 latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude(); 
                 longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude(); 
             }

          } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace(); 
         }

        Log.i(MyMoneyBackActivity.TAG, "Position : " + latitude + " " + longitude);

        point = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);                
        // Add a new marker for this shop
        drawMarker(map, point, rec, "");


    }

    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(this,
                                              getLayoutInflater(),
                                              images));
    //point = new LatLng(CAMERA_LAT, CAMERA_LNG);               
    //drawMarker(map, point, null, "Centro");

    // Display last reading information
    if(mBestReading!=null){
            onLocationChanged(mBestReading);
    }

    if (MyMoneyBackActivity.progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        MyMoneyBackActivity.progressDialog.dismiss();
        MyMoneyBackActivity.progressDialog = null;
    }


}
```

But what I got for some tens of seconds is a completely black screen before the map is actually drawn.

Comment: Try to add code which is not too long as nobody will read a bunch of crappy code - post only really needed part. Also add appropriate question title.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware accelartion and largeheap was the issue in my case. I removed them from the app level and used them in the activity they used.

Issue was in `Manifest`.

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true">
```

Remove from `Manifest` and Use in the `Activity`

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mycompayname.activities.SignUpActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works in Google Play Services 6.7.76 - see here https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7679.

Comment: Google Play Services 6.7.76 is available for download only as an APK. Currently, I am using the whole google-play-services_lib with google-play-services_lib.jar to link it to my project.

Comment: Yes, as I'm talking about the version installed on the device. This is stated in the issue linked, did you read it?

Comment: The version installed in the device is older, yes. What I was trying to explain is that I am quite new to java, so I followed the instructions I found in Internet to download the library and put it in my project. I only see a .jar file in the google-play-services_lib folder, not an apk. How do I link an .apk to my project?